# How to parse a sequence of " " separated values in Haskell

Tags: parsing, haskell

I am a beginner in Haskell and i need to parse a sequence of valuses spearate by something.

The following parser is generated with tokenparser: 
m_semiSep1 p parses and returns a semicolon-separated sequence of one or more p's.

But i dont quite understand how it is created. I need one that returns a comma separated sequence of p`s.  Can you give me a hint how can i do that. I also need to parse a sequence of "=|" separated values but i suppose that it will be the same as with the comma. This is the code i am working on:

```
def = emptyDef{ commentStart = "{-"
          , commentEnd = "-}"
          , identStart = letter
          , identLetter = alphaNum
          , opStart = oneOf "^~&=:-|,"
          , opLetter = oneOf "^~&=:-|,"
          , reservedOpNames = ["~", "&", "^", ":=", "|-", ","]
          , reservedNames = ["true", "false", "nop",
                             "if", "then", "else", "fi",
                             "while", "do", "od"]
          }
TokenParser{ parens = m_parens
       , identifier = m_identifier
       , reservedOp = m_reservedOp
       , reserved = m_reserved
       , semiSep1 = m_semiSep1
       , whiteSpace = m_whiteSpace } = makeTokenParser def
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sepBy` in parsec. `sepBy cell deli` parses something like `cell deli cell deli...`

For example:

```
Prelude> :m Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec
Prelude Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec> let csv = (many letter) `sepBy` (char ',') :: Parser [String]
Prelude Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec> parse csv "" "xx,yy,zz"
Right ["xx","yy","zz"]
```

---

1. https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.9/docs/Text-Parsec-Combinator.html#v:sepBy